# RISC-V generate -1 / 0xFFFFFFFF in a register with LUI / ADDI?

Tags: assembly, riscv

I am learning how to write code for a RISC-V processor.  I want to store a value of `0xFFFFFFFF` into memory / a register.

I can extend the 12 immediate bits of `addi` instruction by adding a `lui` before it,
something like this:

```
lui t0, 0xFFFFF
addi t0, t0, 0x7FF
```

But the result will end up something like `0xFFFFF7FF`.

So then, how can I generate that value?

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [RISC-V build 32-bit constants with LUI and ADDI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50742420) which has the same point about a constant in the [-2048, +2047] range taking only one `addi` with the zero register.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ask a C compiler:

```
unsigned foo(){return 0xFFFFFFFF;}
```

compiles to this asm with Clang `-O3` for RISC-V [**(on Godbolt)**](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'unsigned+int+foo()%7Breturn+0xFFFFFFFF%3B%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:25.00045982931136,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:rv32clang,filters:(___0:(),b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',jquery:'3.2.1',length:1,libraryCode:'1',prevObject:(___0:(sizzle1500417511094:(undefined:(legend:!(5,0,'1')))),length:1,prevObject:(___0:(jQuery3210295089958217274131:(display:''),sizzle1500417511094:(undefined:(legend:!(5,0,'1')))),length:1)),trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'RISC-V+rv32gc+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:35.77256183418933,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:riscv820,filters:(___0:(),b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',jquery:'3.2.1',length:1,libraryCode:'1',prevObject:(___0:(sizzle1500417511094:(undefined:(legend:!(5,0,'1')))),length:1,prevObject:(___0:(jQuery3210295089958217274131:(display:''),sizzle1500417511094:(undefined:(legend:!(5,0,'1')))),length:1)),trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'RISC-V+gcc+8.2.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:39.226978336499315,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4):

```
foo():
    addi    a0, zero, -1
    ret
```

(gcc just uses the `li a0, -1` pseudo-instruction and leaves the details to the assembler.  Normally you should do the same, unless you want to think about choosing constants that can be generated more efficiently.)

---

**RISC-V `addi` sign-extends its immediate operand to 32 (or 64) bits**, so if you want a one in the 12th bit, you need to account for that in your choice for the upper bits.

In this case, the right starting value for the upper bits is `0` so you can optimize away the `lui` entirely.

RISC-V uses 2's complement signed integers so sign-extension just means duplicating the sign bit to all higher positions when widening.

Comment: Related: [RISC-V: Immediate Encoding Variants](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39427092) / [Why are RISC-V S-B and U-J instruction types encoded in this way?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58414772)

Answer (score 3):

Let's first analyse where the problem with your code is:

```
lui t0, 0xFFFFF
addi t0, t0, 0x7FF
```

- The `lui` instruction loads into `t0` the value resulting from left shifting the 20-bit immediate `0xFFFFF` by 12 bits. Therefore, `t0` results in `0xFFFFF000`.
- The `addi` [*sign extends*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension) the 12-bit immediate `0x7FF`, and adds it to the register `t0`. Since the most significant bit (i.e., the sign bit) of the immediate is zero, its sign extended 32-bit value is `0x000007FF`. This value is then added to `t0`, which was previously `0xFFFFF000`. Therefore, the resulting value of `t0` is `0xFFFFF7FF`.

---

As already explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57234946/8012646), you can optimise away the `lui` instruction by taking advantage of how the sign extension works: sign extension propagates the sign bit, which is the most significant bit.

The 12-bit immediate `0xFFF` consists of all `1`s, including the most significant bit (i.e., the sign bit). Therefore, its 32-bit sign extension is `0xFFFFFFFF`, which already corresponds to the value you want:

```
addi t0, zero, 0xFFF
```

If you keep insisting on using both instructions, `lui` and `addi`, simply load all `0`s into the upper bits of `t0`:

```
lui t0, 0
addi t0, t0, 0xFFF
```

Comment: Do note that `addi t0, t0, 0xFFF` is not valid assembly because `0x00000FFF` cannot be represented in a 12 bit immediate.

Comment: @TheThirdOne you are right, but it is not `0x00000FFF` the constant we want to represent. We want `0xFFFFFFFF`. That is, the `0xFFF` immediate in the `addi` will be sign extended to `0xFFFFFFFF`.  I was just introducing a superfluous `lui` instruction because OP insisted on using `lui`+`addi`.

Comment: I understood that it is intended to be sign-extended, but I am not aware of any assembler that accepts that as valid code. It is reasonable to explain how immediates work, but if readers try to use that in real code, they will have issues.