# How exactly does the RISC-V immediate encoding notation work?

Tags: assembly, encoding, riscv, machine-code, immediate-operand

I thought I've understood this but I think I've confused myself.

[image: RISC-V RV32G Encoding]

I was under the impression that [11:0] was the order of the immediate bits within the encoding. As an example, `addi x1, x2, 12` would have an immediate of 000000001100; the immediate would start at bit 20 within the `addi` instruction encoding.

I'm confused how this logic applies to the same notation used within the U-type encoding [31:12]. I understand the U-type immediate is 20 bits but I'm now unsure of how to interpret the notation.

Comment: Okay, this is sinking in more. The greatest decimal value that can be used as an immediate within the `lui` instruction would be (2^31/2)-1 then?

Comment: No, `(2^32 - 1) & -4096` = 4294963200 = 0xfffff000.  (As an address, the address of the highest 4k page in the low 4GiB of virtual address space.)  Any pattern in the high 20, all-zero in the low 12.

Answer (score 2):

U-type is for `lui`, where the immediate goes into the *high* 20 bits of Rd, and the lower 12 bits are cleared.  Or for `auipc`, same decoding; bits `[31:12]` come from the instruction, the low 12 are implicit 0.

So the bit-numbers are the position *within the decoded value*, not just within the immediate itself.

The position within the diagram shows you where each value-bit *comes from* in the machine encoding; **the `[hi:lo]` bit-range numbers show you which value bit (in a full 32 or 64-bit integer) this field maps to.**

For more general stuff about the rest of RISC-V immediates, see the design comments in the ISA docs, quoted and expanded upon in a couple SO Q&As:

- [Why are RISC-V S-B and U-J instruction types encoded in this way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58414772/why-are-risc-v-s-b-and-u-j-instruction-types-encoded-in-this-way)
- [RISC-V: Immediate Encoding Variants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39427092/risc-v-immediate-encoding-variants)