# How do I concatenate immediate value of type B RISC-V instruction?

Tags: assembly, riscv, instruction-encoding, immediate-operand

I have the following binary from a RISC-V instruction that I need to decode: `11111110000011100001100011100011`

Using the [RISC-V](https://www.cs.sfu.ca/%7Eashriram/Courses/CS295/assets/notebooks/RISCV/RISCV_CARD.pdf) reference card, I know the following information:

- Its `opcode` is `1100011`, meaning it is a B-type format instruction
- Its `funct3` is `001` = `0x1`, meaning `bne` (Branch !=)
- Register `rs1` is `11100` = `x28` or `t3`
- Register `rs2` is `00000` = `x0` or `zero`

So far, the instruction should look like `bne t3 zero`, but I am missing the immediate value. I have the following:

- `imm[12]` = `1`
- `imm[11]` = `1`
- `imm[10:5]` = `111111`
- `imm[4:1]` = `1000`

I am unable to understand how these should be concatenated/ordered in order to get the immediate value for the instruction. I assumed something like `111111111000`, but what do I do from there?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, bits 12, 11, 10 through 5, and 4 through 1 of the immediate are separate fields in the instruction.  Bit 0 is implicitly zero since branch targets are always aligned by 2 (2-byte compressed instructions are a thing), so you're missing a low `0`.  Put them together in that order like you've done, sign-extend to 32 or 64-bit, then consult the documentation for the instruction to see what it means.  (In this case it's a relative displacement, IIRC relative to the start of the branch instruction, unlike in some other ISAs where it's often relative to the end.)

Comment: So close! As Peter says, `imm[0]` is (implicitly) 0, so now you have the whole 13-bit immediate!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's correct: bits 12, 11, 10 through 5, and 4 through 1 of the immediate are separate fields in the instruction.

**Bit 0 is implicitly zero** since branch targets are always aligned by 2 (2-byte compressed instructions are a thing), so you're missing a low 0.  In other words, left-shift by 1 on the value you have now.

Put them together in that order like you've done (with `imm[0]=0`), sign-extend to 32 or 64-bit, then consult the documentation for the instruction to see what it means.  (RISC-V immediate operands are always sign-extended, not zero-extended.)

In this case it's a relative displacement, IIRC relative to the start of the branch instruction, unlike in some other ISAs where it's often relative to the end.

In general, see *[RISC-V: Immediate Encoding Variants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39427092/risc-v-immediate-encoding-variants)* for diagrams of where the immediate fields are, and the rationale for the design decision to break them up that way in different instruction formats. (Minimizing muxes and gate-delays for decoding different instruction formats, e.g. making sign-extension able to get started right away, unconditionally from the top bit of the instruction word.)

Also related: *[How exactly does the RISC-V immediate encoding notation work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67354485/how-exactly-does-the-risc-v-immediate-encoding-notation-work)*